# "Math Processing Error" when processing LaTeX using knitr in R

Tags: r, knitr, mathjax, markdown

I've never had any problem with my Latex appearing properly when using knitr before, but recently when I compile my document, I get this error:

[image: mathjax]

I'm not sure why this is happening.  The error output I'm getting on the bottom of my HTML document says:

```
Loading Web-Font TeX/Math/Italic  
File failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/html_preview/mathjax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/png/imagedata.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/imageFonts.js
```

If anyone has any ideas or has seen anything like this happening when compiling LaTex when using knitr in R and has any recommendations on how to go about solving this issue, I'd be grateful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a MathJax issue.  Do you have the MathJax fonts installed?  Did anything change in your MathJax configuration lately?

Comment: I haven't tweaked any MathJax fonts...however, I did change my working directory.

Comment: It looks like MathJax cannot find any fonts. The `XXXXX` port number in the url seems rather strange.

Comment: Mathjax specific questions are off topic for this site, if you click on the mathjax wiki link you get links to the mathjax help forum or stack overflow.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, and the software versions. There are too many unknown pieces of information here.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too and it appeared to be because I had saved the `.Rmd` file in a different directory to R's default one.

i.e, my default R directory is

```
getwd()
"C:/Users/Dave/Documents"
```

When I create and run a `.Rmd` file from the default directory the maths symbols render fine.

However, if I create and save a `.Rmd` file in a different directory I get the same errors as you. I don't know **why** this is the case, but saving my `.Rmd` file in the default location solved the issue.

Comment: Actually, you can also use `setwd` function to change default folder to one, where the `.Rmd` file is.

Comment: Yes, I normally create new files for each project and set the working directory using `setwd()`. However, `knitr` doesn't like this for some reason and can't render the maths symbols

Comment: And can you share an example? I have no problem with separate folders...

Comment: I've uploaded two screenshots to my github: https://github.com/tospig/Machine_Learning_Stanford_R

Comment: Further to my last, I tried a directory one below R's default one and the rendering worked. 
To summarise:
`"C:/Users/Dave/Documents"` - default directory - works.
`"C:/Users/Dave/Documents/temp"` - works.
`"C:/Dave's files/temp"` - fails.